# Page Speed Issues

Tags: web, pagespeed

Really having lots of page speed issues, my web developer tried a cdn for the banner loading which made it really fast, but now she has amended this and the speed has really dropped very low again.
Any suggestions on howto rectify this?
website www.buypromoproducts.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

Without having any more information on your site it is very difficult to help you out.  Have you tried using tools that tell you where your site is being slow and provide recommendations, for example [Google Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)?

Comment: Hi Yes, using Google Page Speed Insights, Mobile is now scoring 42 and desktop 84 , I really want to achieve some better results.What further information would you like, feel like we have been trying to achieve this for so long without great success

Comment: Hi, yes tried Google Page Speed insights and still not great